# How do I change the amount of health players have in Rec-Room?

Tags: rec-room

Is there a way to change the default amount of health on Rec-Room?

I see too many people having one-shot kill PVP and I find it ridiculous. I want to add some health to them so that they're immune to at least 5 shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Two ways to change health:

1. The [Game Rules Chip](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Rules_Chip) allows you to change how much health and shield a player generally has and if/how/when it should regenerate.
2. You can switch to manual health management by disabling the respective settings in the Game Rules Chip, and using the [Player Hit Chip](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Chips#Player_Hit) instead. When a player gets shot, it outputs the player who shot and have been shot, as well as their teams and the damage. Now you have 2 options:

   1. Simply [respawn a player when he is hit](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Circuit_Diagrams#Spawn_On_Hit).
   2. Use the [get](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Chips#Get_Player_Stat) and [set](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Chips#Set_Player_Stat) player stats chips to count hits, manage the players health manually, etc.